# how to evaluate a mathematical function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am a novice in matlab and currently searching, how to solve a mathematical function in matlab.

It's what i want, i want to solve a function f(x)=x^2+2x+1, where x=2.
I want to take x^2+2x+1 and 2 as input and show the output.

from this [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Portable_Functions), i saw how to solve a mathematical function.
Procedure available in the link is:

```
>>f = @(x) 2*x^2-3*x+4;
>>f(3)
ans = 13
```

So, i wrote the following part in my script:

```
F=input('enter function: ','s');
v = input('parameter: ');
f=@(x)F;
disp(f(v));
```

when i provide x+1 and 3 as input, the ans i am getting is x+1. How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a BIG difference between solving a function and evaluating it! Which do you wish to do? Be clear.

Comment: i wanted procedure of solving. another user changed the title.

Comment: Yes, but "solving" an equation is not what you are looking to do. It is indeed an evaluation.

Comment: thanks for the info. i didn't give it much thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `F` variable is a **string** that simply says `"x + 1"`. You'll have to ask matlab to interpret this string as a function in order to get a numerical value.

One way of doing so would be using `eval`

```
F = input('enter function: ', 's' );
v = input('parameter: ');
myfun = sprintf('@( %s ) %s', v, F ); % a string
f = eval( myFun ); % interpret string as a command
f( 3 ), % do the math - evaulate F(3)
```

**EDIT,**  a clarification based on comments below:
The above solution assumes `F`, the input string representing the mathematical formula may have user-chosen variable (i.e., the unknown does not have to be `'x'`, it may be `'y'`, `'a'` etc.) In order to comunicate this, `v` is a char storing this information.

In case where `F` always depends on `'x'`, and the desired output is `F(v)` for a numeric value `v` the following modification is needed:

```
myfun = sprintf('@(x) %s', F );
f = eval(myfun);
F_of_v = f( v )
```

Comment: when i write ur part in the script, it's giving following error:
ERROR STARTS>>
> In Untitled at 3
??? Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or
expressions.

Error in ==> Untitled at 4
f = eval( myfun ); % interpret string as a command
<<ERROR ENDS

as the parameter value will be integer, i replaced your 3rd line with "myfun = sprintf('@( %i ) %s', v, F );", it giving the following error:

ERROR START >>
??? Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Error in ==> Untitled at 4
f = eval( myfun ); % interpret string as a command
<<ERROR ENDS

what's the problem?

thanks!

Comment: @shaashwato There should be: `myfun = sprintf('@( x ) %s', F ); f = eval( myfun );f( v )`.

Comment: @Marcin the "name" of the argument of `F` is not `'x'` - it is to be decided by the user using the input `v`. For example, the user may supply `F = 'y + 2'` and request the parameter to be `v = 'y'`.

Comment: @shaashwato replace `%i` back to `%s` in line 3.

Comment: @Shai v = 3, not 'y' in my view.

Comment: @Marcin I guess this is what shaashwato meant - it was not too clear from the question.